# How can I use D&D 3.5e monsters in WoTRPG?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters, conversion

I have the Wheel of Time RPG, but I'm thinking about using it for some non-Wheel of Time adventures (Mostly because it's a medieval d20 system **that I already own** and feels more *gritty* than 5e or 4e, which is appropriate for the Lovecraftian campaign I'm aiming for. Also, the magical madness system seems awesome for this.) So, since I also have a 3.5 monster manual, I was wondering what would I have to do to convert from 3.5 to WoTRPG?

Comment: Considering the existence of a freely available SRD, what is your reason for not playing straight 3.5 in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Well, since WoTRPG was designed by D&D folks with a feats and skills system very similar to D&D 3.0, you should needn't to do much. But if are interested in the mechanics of adapting one similar system, to another I would suggest you download a pdf copy of or simply read online Paizo's system of converstion from 3.5 to Pathfinder and that might give you some ideas.